# Understanding Google reCaptcha V3 purpose and how to handle failures ? Google reCatpcha

Tags: authentication, captcha, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

I understand Captcha helps us to avoid BOTs signup in to our website and create fake accounts. To avoid it, we use the Captcha feature so that BOTs find it difficult to auto Register. However,with advanced products like "Google reCaptcha V3" , the users are not allowed to face a challenge, rather, the advanced algorithm detects the BOTS and returns the results.
In such a scenario, what can we do to help avoid false positives getting blocked?

Do we reimplement a Catcpha Challenge which will comeup if the V3 detects a BOT? Does it then not make the V3 solution incomplete?

As per Google - We need to implement a 2Factor Auth step for stop the Bots. But how will this be achieved if the BOT can easily read messages from a mobile number? ( Lets say we setup a OTP ?). And if this is true, what is the whole point of 2Factor Authentication as BOTs can even try to do OTP/email validation?

Overall, I am confused how to use the Google ReCaptcha V3 solution when failures happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of how Google handles with false positives. But I know Google's reCAPTCHA 3, which is invisible and will return a risk level number to the customers. Then it should be the customers themselves taking actions. Also reCAPTCHA v3 could work together with v2(the picture one). 2Factor authentication can also be combined with a CAPTCHA integrating before sending the message. Only when the user pass the CAPTCHA, a short message could be sent to their phones. It is a general practice for many mobile apps and websites.